# Wohnen vs kommen?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

I am a new student. In my German textbook, the authors use the verb *wohnen* when used in sentences when asking where you are from while in the books and documents I got from Germany the verb *kommen* is used. What do you as native speaker consider being the norm and most correct?

> Woher kommst du?
>   Wo kommst du her?

vs.

> Wo wohnst du?

For me it feels more natural to use *kommen*, for example:

> Ich komme aus Schweden

rather than

> Ich wohne in Stockholm, Stockholm liegt in Schweden.

or

> Ich wohne in Stockholm, in Schweden.

Comment: Beispiele aus dem Textbuch wären schön, denn die Aussage klingt nicht plausibel. Woher man kommt und wo man wohnt sind zwei unterschiedliche Fragen.

Answer (score 6):

> Woher kommst du?

This is the variant of "where do you come from?" most often used in "official" German (such as newspapers or in television).

> Wo kommst du her?

This variant is often used in everyday German.

> Wo wohnst du?

This means: "Where do you live?"

In your case the answer to `Woher kommst du?` would typically be the country or the city where you originally came from.

The answer to `Wo wohnst du?` would be the city or building where you currently live (for example the city where your apartment is).

Depending on the context the person asking you `Wo wohnst du?` just wants to hear "in an apartment" or "in the hotel" or a similar statement.

On the other hand depending on the context the answer to the question `Woher kommst du?` may also be "I come from shopping"...

Comment: Vielen Dank. You were first and you got the point/s.

Comment: @Eva Please consider to mark this answer as "accepted", if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say.

The phrase

> Wo wohnst du?

could be interpreted as 'So. Where is your place (in the city)?'. You look more curious. It's a directer, straight forward question. It can be good (a friend is asking) or not so good (Cop is asking).

> Wo kommst du her?

Can be used online, in a direct talk and is more polite.

Comment: Martin Rosenau picked up what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

The two verbs have a different nuance to them.

> Woher kommst du?

The verb *kommen* (and the related *herkommen* as in ‘Wo kommst du her?’) are asking for your *origin.* They do not necessarily ask for where you are living at the moment. The typical answer would be a region or a country, but cities might be given as well.

> Wo wohnst du?

The verb *wohnen* explicitly asks for your current residential address and nothing else. The precision of your answer is typically indirectly proportional to the distance to said address.

Example showing the duality:

> Wo wohnst du?
>
> Ich wohne in Braunschweig, aber ich komme aus Bayern.

**Note:** Many people may feel offended if you ask them ‘woher kommst du?’, at first meeting. Typically those that look oriental, Asian or African — remember that there is a slight implication of ‘this place here isn’t where you were born, is it?’